# Suggestion for Authnet AIM/CIM membership site

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim, authorize.net-aim

I have built a software solution for recurring billing using ARB and I now have the task of using AIM and CIM. I have searched for an hour before asking just as an FYI.

I assume for single transactions I use AIM. Then, to store the card on Authnet servers for future charges I use createCustomerProfile followed by createCustomerPaymentProfile.

My question is this:
Should I use AIM to charge the card, if its successful then I make the call to createCustomerProfile and use the return id for createCustomerPaymentProfile.

I know this seems like a simple question but I just want to be sure before I start into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You always want to use AIM first as it is both fast and allows you the opportunity to verify the card is valid before creating a CIM profile.

Comment: Excellent, funny you answered, I'm actually using your AuthNet class! Thanks!